# Ubuntu 20.04 hibernates instantly when power cord is unplugged

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery, hibernate

I'm running a Fujitsu Lifebook U Series with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 as dual boot. Every once in a while, when I detach the power cord, Ubuntu responds by going to hibernation immediately, meaning I need to reawaken the system by pressing the power button and log back in.

It's a small annoyance, but an annoyance nonetheless, and the strangest thing is this doesn't happen regularly at all; I'd say it happens maybe once every 20 times I detach the cord, possibly much less often, and I can't see it being correlated with anything specific. The laptop's battery is working perfectly fine. dmesg logs provide no useful information.

Any idea as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Hello. Based on what you have written here all that anyone could give is a guess.

Comment: Reset the Power Manager by, shutdown the computer, hold down the POWER button for ~30 seconds, reboot and retest. Report back. If that solves the problem, I'll write a formal answer for you. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.